# Single update query to update a single document (containing subarray documents)?

Tags: mongodb, replace, sub-array

I have an existing document in DB:

Plan Collection (In DB):

```
{ _id: ObjectId('XXX'),
  name: 'Plan A', 
  remark: 'YYY',
  products: [ {name: 'Pdt1', qty: '10'}, 
              {name: 'Pdt2', qty: '20'} ]
}
```

I need to do update to 'Plan A' doc with products entirely to below (no matching required to existing products in DB) below:

```
{ _id: ObjectId('XXX'),
  name: 'Plan A',
  remark: 'edited YYY',
  products: [ {name: 'Pdt1', qty: '10'},
              {name: 'Pdt3', qty: '30'},
              {name: 'Pdt4', qty: '40'}  ]
```

**Question:**

Is there a simple MongoDB way to update existing 'Plan A' document to **update** its fields + **replace** all products subarrays in DB? Thank you

Comment: *is there a simple MongoDB way* if you are searching for simple query then can you please add complex query that you have tried in your question.

Comment: @turivishal, I am thinking if I need not do any 'delete', 'insert', 'update' to existing subarray, but to overwrite the subarray entirely (no checking required). Not sure if your comment is saying I need to do that, which doesn't help in my question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can use `$set` to replace a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace the entire product subdocument you can do it with positional all [`$[]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-all-elements-in-an-array) operator in MongoDb 3.6+

```
var filter = {
    name: 'Plan A'
};

var update = {
    $set: {
        'products.$[]': [ 
            {name: 'Pdt1', qty: '10'},
            {name: 'Pdt3', qty: '30'},
            {name: 'Pdt4', qty: '40'}  
        ]
    }
};

var options = {
    multi: true
};

db.collection.update(filter, update, options);
```

Comment: thanks. Indeed $set can easily solve the problem, This is what I do:  $set: {remark: req.body.remark, products: req.body.products}. It will then replace entire doc (its fields + its subarrays) together and solve my question.